# Python - Passing variables between a class function incorrectly?

Tags: python, class, pass-by-reference, local-variables

The program is rather self-explanatory. I've begun playing around with the basics of Python, and am really lost on this one. I am used to C++ and the wonderful ability to pass things by reference. But, in this, the class variable I'm trying to change (Fighter.statHEALTH) won't change, and I've read that it's because integers are immutable and it just creates a new object locally. So how in the world can I make the change apply to the original variable? I've Googled and Googled, but to no avail. I don't want to perform some ugly manuever like making a list and passing it if I don't have to.

```
#python 3.2.2

#   Create a small test project to have combat between two entities.    #
#   Combat should include 3 different stats: statATK, statDEF, and statHEALTH.  #
#   The two entities should be of the same class.   #

class Fighter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.statHEALTH = 10
        self.statATK = 3
        self.statDEF = 3

    def attack(self, enemyhealth):
        enemyhealth = (enemyhealth - self.statATK)
        return enemyhealth

    def defend(self):
        statDEF += 1


def main():
    James = Fighter()
    Keaton = Fighter()
    while James.statHEALTH > 0:
        print("Do you wish to attack or defend?")
        print("1. Attack")
        print("2. Defend")
        choice = input()
        if choice == "1":
            James.attack(Keaton.statHEALTH)
            print("You did", James.statATK, "damage!") 
            Keaton.attack(James.statHEALTH)
            print("Keaton has", Keaton.statHEALTH, "health left.")
            print("Keaton did", Keaton.statATK, "damage!")
            print("You have", James.statHEALTH, "health left.")
        #elif choice == "2":
            #James.defend()
            #Keaton.attack(James.statHEALTH)

main()
```

Comment: Keaton should attack James, not James's health ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def attack(self, enemyhealth):
    enemyhealth = (enemyhealth - self.statATK)
    return enemyhealth
```

This would actually work if you changed your call to be

```
Keaton.statHEALTH = James.attack(Keaton.statHEALTH)
```

.. since you `return` the damage from the attack.  Obviously this is ugly; repeating yourself is not good.  Instead you can make `attack` look like:

```
def attack(self, other):
    other.statHEALTH -= self.statATK
```

And then just do

```
James.attack(Keaton)
```

when you call it.

Comment: This is the problem. Very simple, but i mised it. +1

Comment: I actually didn't mean to leave both of those things in there were I was repeating myself, the return was part of a solution I'd found after searching that I hoped would work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could think of it differently. In your example, `Fighter.attack()` just returns the value of the enemies health after the attack. So really, it should be a method call on the enemy's object. You could add a method that decreases the fighter's health when they get attacked:

```
def attack(self, enemy):
    enemy.getAttacked(self.statATK)

def getAttacked(self, ATK):
    self.statHEALTH -= ATK
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
while James.statHEALTH > 0:
    #print statements
    if choice == "1":
        the_attack = James.attack(Keaton)
```

Then define your classes as:

```
class Fighter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.statHEALTH = 10
        self.statATK = 3
        self.statDEF = 3

    def attack(self,target):
        attack_details = target.takedamage(self.statATK)
        return attack_details

    def takedamage(self,dmg):
        modified_dmg = dmg-self.statDEF
        self.statHEALTH -= modified_dmg
        return modified_dmg
```

This has the added benefit of being easily expandable, e.g. you can add a hit table (`for i in random.randint(1,100) if i < 20: #miss; elif 20 <= i < 80: #hit; elif 80<= i: #crit`) or resistances for certain elements or add a flag that allows your defender to counterattack in their `takedamage` function (perhaps calling a new function `getcountered` to prevent infinite looping).

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't really that you can't pass things by references in Python. In fact, you *always* pass values by reference; Python never copies values unless you ask it to.

Or, more accurately, that whole C-based terminology is misleading in Python.

Anyway, when you do this:

```
James.attack(Keaton.statHEALTH)
```

This doesn't make a copy of the value in `Keaton.statHEALTH`, it passes a reference to the exact same value. So, when `attack` starts, your `enemyhealth` variable is a name for that value.

And then you do this:

```
enemyhealth = (enemyhealth - self.statATK)
```

… the `enemyhealth - self.statATK` returns a new value, and then you bind that new value to the `enemyhealth` name. This has no effect on any other names for the old value.

There are two ways to solve this.

---

First, you don't actually *need* to mutate anything here. You're already doing `return enemyhealth` at the end. That means the caller can get the new value that you calculated. So why not just use that?

```
Keaton.statHEALTH = James.attack(Keaton.statHEALTH)
```

And then everything works.

---

Of course in C++, you can mutate integer values. This seems a little silly when you think about it—turning the number 24 into the number 19 would break a lot of math, and probably make the universe stop working, and Python just isn't that powerful.

But you can easily build a type that *can* be sensibly mutated. In fact, you've already built one: a `Fighter` holds an integer health value, but can be changed to hold a different one instead. So, you could write this:

```
def attack(self, enemy):
    enemy.health = enemy.health - self.statATK
```

And then:

```
James.attack(Keaton)
```

Just as calling the old method with `Keaton.health` made `enemyhealth` into another reference to the same number, calling the new method with `Keaton` makes `enemy` into a reference to the same `Fighter`. If you just reassigned a new value to `enemy`, that wouldn't have any effect on the old value, the one that `Keaton` refers to. But if you change the value in-place, obviously `Keaton` is still referring to that now-changed value.

Comment: Thank you, but you'd been beaten to the answer. I still really appreciate it and your answer gave me a bit of a deeper understanding of the problem at hand.